# Does 7-Zip really run multiple rounds of SHA-256 when key stretching?

Tags: sha256, key-stretching, 7zip

Recently I was testing whether I could make 7-Zip archives more bruteforce-resistant. Both [someone on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=7z&oldid=752759960&diff=prev&diffmode=visual) and [@kelalaka](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/240076/15648) on this website make the following claim:

> The 7z format supports encryption with the AES algorithm with a 256-bit key. The key is generated from a user-supplied passphrase using an algorithm based on the SHA-256 hash function. The SHA-256 is executed 2<sup>18</sup> (262144) times, which causes a significant delay on slow PCs before compression or extraction starts. This technique is called key stretching and is used to make a brute-force search for the passphrase more difficult. Current GPU-based, and custom hardware attacks limit the effectiveness of this particular method of key stretching, so it is still important to choose a strong password. The 7z format provides the option to encrypt the filenames of a 7z archive.

> 7zip uses 2^19-times iterated SHA256 to derive the AES-256 key from passwords.

The problem is that I cannot verify this claim. I grepped for various keywords and the closest I got was the following piece of code:

```
[20:19:36]  d33tah@d33tah-pc:/tmp/p7zip-16.02+dfsg(0) > grep -A10 'static void DeriveKey2' CPP/7zip/Crypto/ZipStrong.cpp
static void DeriveKey2(const Byte *digest, Byte c, Byte *dest)
{
  Byte buf[64];
  memset(buf, c, 64);
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < NSha1::kDigestSize; i++)
    buf[i] ^= digest[i];
  NSha1::CContext sha;
  sha.Init();
  sha.Update(buf, 64);
  sha.Final(dest);
}
```

However, it's not [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1), but xor. Am I looking at the wrong place in the source code? Here's a GitHub repository I found for convenience (grepping was done on the result of `apt-get source p7zip-full`).

Comment: You might need to look in `7zAes.cpp`. `ZipStrong.cpp` might only be used for `zip` archives, not `7z` archives.

Comment: It's worth noting that this type of key stretching is no longer recommended because it is not memory-hard. 7zip would be better off if they switched to Argon2.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The relevant code for 7z key derivation is in 7zAES.cpp function [CKeyInfo::CalcKey](https://github.com/btolab/p7zip/blob/f30c859433af90937723dd4e808a24c3bb836711/CPP/7zip/Crypto/7zAes.cpp#L37) and it matches the description about SHA-256 and number of rounds.

Comment: I actually appears to be calculating the SHA-256 of a byte stream composed of n repetitions of the concatenation of: salt, password, incrementing 64-bit little-endian counter. The output of the SHA-256 is not fed back into to SHA-256 (which is what a casual reader of the OP's quoted text might infer).